# Task Parallel library continuation

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

OK, so I'm creating a method to login a DataProvider class with a soap service. The login will make three separate soap calls and combine all their responses into a single callback to the ViewController on successful login. I'm wanting to use the Task parallel library to achieve this (but at this point its caused me nothing but headaches). I'd also have a requirement that any exceptions that may occur in the "LoginAsync" method be passed back to the view controller class for logging purposes.

The code (which isn't compiling) at the minute is:

```
public void LoginAsync(string username, string password, Action<int,SystemConfig,string> callback)
{
    Task<int> task = Task<int>.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        int result = _service.Login(username, password);
        if (result == 1)
        {
                _header.AuthenticationToken = _service.GenerateToken();
                _systemConfig = _service.GetSystemConfig(_cultureCode);
        }
        return result;
    }).ContinueWith((Task<int> antecedent) =>
    {
            callback(antecedent.Result, _systemConfig, _header.AuthenticationToken);
    }, CancellationToken.None, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext(), TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion);
    }
```

No matter how many different ways I try this I cannot seem to get it working so as I can address all my requirements. At the minute the compilation error is complaining about the antecedent parameter.

Comment: are you tasking out Login that in turn tasks out the actual login?

Comment: @LucasAbilidebob Mine were a nice abusive cyan... I recycled that power.

Comment: I ask this because your method is named LoginAsync, the tells me that the LoginAsync method is being called via a thread/task yes?  Then you task out the login again?  to do what you want is simple.

Comment: LoginAsync is just called by the ViewController (Xamarin.Android app) when the button is clicked. So it's just the UI thread calling the LoginAsync method. You see I've been changing this code back and forth a whole multitude of ways over the last day or two and so it is a mess now. I'm wanting to write, good maintainable code but the TPL and this design pattern is all new to me.

Comment: @TMcKeown Yes, but to be perfectly honest I've lost the plot at this stage and have meandered from what my intentions were at the start because of not being familar with the TPL. Feel free to completely rip into my means of structuring this code. I'd like to do it right.

Comment: Everything is blue ;O